# How to get the ID of a user's YouTube featured video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can I get the video ID (and/or other metadata) about the video featured on a user's YouTube page? I've searched the YouTube API docs with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with screen scraping?

If so, look for the following div tag with class "channels-featured-video-details". Then look for a link to the video inside that has the id in it: href="/watch?v=QgACcUDttQ0"

```
<div class="channels-featured-video-details yt-tile-visible clearfix">
  <h3 class="title">
    <a href="/watch?v=QgACcUDttQ0&amp;feature=plcp" class="yt-uix-sessionlink" data-sessionlink="ei=COiLg4Kc97ICFaERIQod2UYSHQ%3D%3D&amp;feature=plcp">
...
```